# Logic of a bit masking XOR code

Tags: c, logic, hardware, bit

I have a code that changes two sets of hex numbers and then stores them into a new unsigned char. The code looks like the following:

```
unsigned char OldSw = 0x1D;
unsigned char NewSw = 0xF0;
unsgined char ChangedSw;

ChangedSw = (OldSw ^ ~NewSw) & ~OldSw;
```

So what I know is:

0x1D = 0001 1101

0xF0 = 1111 0000

Im confused on what the changedSw line is doing. I know it will give the output 0x02 but I can not figure out how its doing it.

Comment: Perform the operations, one by one, on paper. First do the inversion of `NewSw`, then the XOR, then the inversion of `OldSw` and finally the AND. Then you will know exactly what's happening and why.

Comment: So NewSw would become 0000 1111 after inversion correct? Then XOR would bring it to 0x0D. Then I would AND that with the inverted oldSw?

Comment: Yes, that's what happening.

Comment: That's just a complicated way of writing `ChangedSw = ~ (OldSw | NewSw);` .

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Nope. XOR makes zero if both bits equal.

Comment: @kotlomoy Damn it's to early, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ChangedSw = (OldSw ^ ~NewSw) & ~OldSw;`

It means "zero one part of `OldSw` and inverse other part". `NewSw` indicates what bits of `OldSw` to zero and what bits to inverse. Namely, 1's in `NewSw` indicate bits to be zeroed, 0's indicate bits to be inverted.

This operation implemented in two steps.

Step 1. Invert bits.

`(OldSw ^ ~NewSw)`:

```
  0001 1101
^ 0000 1111
  ---------
  0001 0010
```

See, we inverted bits which were 0's in original `NewSw`.

Step 2. Zero bits which were not inverted in previous step.

`& ~OldSw`:

```
  0001 0010
& 1110 0010
  ---------
  0000 0010
```

See, it doesn't change inverted bits, but zero all the rest.

Comment: `& ~OldSw` zeros the bits that are zero in oldSW, not the bits which were not inverted in the previous step. Also *"1's in NewSw indicate bits to be zeroed"* is misleading.

Comment: @MartinR "zeros the bits that are zero in oldSW" - what does it mean? Bit 1 is zero in OldSw but result is 0x02. See, bit 1 is only not zero bit in result. How it could be zeroed?

Comment: Sorry, I got it the wrong way around. `& ~OldSw` zeroes the bits that are *one* in OldSW. My point was only that this step is independent of NewSw and independent of the previous step.

Comment: Your *computation* is correct, my comment refers only to the explaining text.

Answer (score -1):

the first part would be 1F ie. 0001 1111.So when ended with ~oldsw(1110 0010)
the  operation will be something like this:

```
0001 1111
1110 0010
----------
0000 0010
```

So the output will be 2. The tilde operator is 1's complement.

Comment: How did you get the 1F?

Comment: The answer is incorrect. The intermediate step, i.e. `OldSw ^ ~NewSw` is not `0x1F`. It should be `0001 0010` or `0x12`